# Is there a way to get/nslog an array of all local variables in a function in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I want to do something like this :

```
-(void)doSomething
{
    NSObject* objectA = [NSObject new];
    NSObject* objectB = [NSObject new];
    NSLog(@"%@",__LOCAL_VARIABLES__);
}
```

Result on the console is something like:

```
objectA = <NSObject: 0xc9e5d40>,
objectB = <NSObject: 0xc9e6020>
```

Comment: You won't find a general solution to this, or at least one that doesn't require you to declare the array yourself.  You cannot predict what variable will reside in each part of the stack frame, or how the compiler will allocate them at any given moment in time.

Comment: Aren't breakpoints used for this?

Comment: No breakpoints, just NSLOG

Comment: I don't think it can be done.

Comment: I'm saying you could use breakpoints to look at your local variables.

Comment: yeah, I do that most of the time, but it would be very handy sometimes if this was possible.

Comment: What it would take would be a swizzle on top of the Objective-C source preprocessor that would identify all of the "visible" locals in a method (keeping in mind scoping within blocks, etc) and generate the code for the NSLog parm list.  Doable, but nontrivial, and probably not worth the effort.  (I don't offhand know of any other language that has this facility either.)

Comment: I'd check this project https://github.com/heardrwt/RHObjectiveBeagle as a good starting point